# The Pre-image of $ x sin(\frac{1}{x})$ of a zero set

Tags: real-analysis

I came across a problem on Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*, which is about the integrability of this composite function $f(\phi(x))$, where f is known to be Riemann-integrable on  $[-1,1]$, and $\phi$ is defined on $[0,1]$,  $\phi(x) =
\begin{cases}
x*\sin(1/x),  & \text{if $x>0$ and $x\leq1$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

Now I need to prove that $f(\phi(x))$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$. Actually I know that by *Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem* I only need to prove that for every zero set $Z⊂[-1,1]$, $\phi^{pre}(Z)$ is a zero set in $[0,1]$. But I am now having difficulty proving it. Is this true? Or maybe I am in the wrong way.

I would be pleased if you help me with proof of this fact or if you give me some hints about my original question.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But here the inside function is specified, and I am asked to prove that this composite function **is** Integrable.

Comment: Actually, if I can prove that the pre-image of a zero set is a zero set (for $\phi$ ), I can prove that the discontinuity of $f(\phi(x))$ is a zero set because $\phi$ is continuous. All the discontinuity point must come from $f$. More precisely, if the pre-image of the discontinuity points' set of $f$(which is a zero set since $f$ is integrable) is a zero set, then $f(\phi(x))$ is Riemann integrable by _Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem_.